# VBA Run time error 424: Object required

Tags: vba, object, required

I have a simple code to find first and last row populated in excel. When I execute this I get error VBA Run time error 424: Object required. 
I searched other 424: object required errors but it doesn't give specifics on this particular logic. I tried Lf both as integer and string.

```
Sub lastrow()
Dim Lf As Integer
Lf = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, Range("Lastrow").Column).End(xlUp).Row
End Sub
```

Can anyone please help with this?

Comment: is `Lastrow` a workbook or worksheet scoped named range?

Comment: No repro, but `Lf` should be a `Long`, otherwise it will overflow an `Integer` at row 32,768. And `Range("Lastrow")` isn't qualified and thus implicitly refers to the active sheet, which might not be the `sht` worksheet.

Comment: Lastrow is a cell name and not a sheet. When data is entered in the cell, I want to find first row starting with cell: Lastrow and Lastrow of cell:Lastrow

Comment: Yes, I meant `Range` isn't qualified, i.e. should be `sht.Range`, not just `Range`

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this error by activating worksheet as below:

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
```

Comment: Try avoiding using `ActiveWorkbook` and `ActiveSheet`, instead use names, like `Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Name_of_your_Sheet")`